# How to use Dropbox API to get most recent file in Github pages site

Tags: javascript, html, css, dropbox-api

I'm currently trying to use the Dropbox API in a Github pages website to get the most recent file in Dropbox and use the title of it to change CSS background color. However, I can't seem to figure out how to write the js to use the Dropbox API. I have the access token which I have replaced with Insert_Access_Token_Here in the code I provided. The code below is a test that should print my files in the console, but doesn't. Can someone give me a clear way, from scratch, how I can use the Dropbox API to at least get the name of the most recent file. (Can I import Dropbox api using cdn cloudflaire?) Thank you

```
<script type="module" >
      import { Dropbox } from '../node_modules/dropbox';
      const dbx = new Dropbox({
        accessToken: 'Insert_Access_Token_Here',
        fetch
      })
      dbx.filesListFolder({
        path: ''
      }).then(res => console.log(res))
</script>
```

The error message I keep getting in the console is

> net::ERR_ABORTED 404

Answer (score 0):

I want to leave this here because it might help some other people who were confused by the API, but I figured it out. You can use

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropbox.js/4.0.30/Dropbox-sdk.js" integrity="sha256-B2oONvdKJ3qkdcGzlVZwhFz55Pk6/+clzI+9hbK1C24=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fetch/2.0.3/fetch.js"></script>
```

in the `<head>` tag, and then under `<script>` in `<body>` you can put

```
var dbx = new Dropbox.Dropbox({ accessToken: 'Enter_Access_Token_Here' });
```

and you're good to go to use API commands.